# Run specific jobs in gitlab scheduled pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have composed a gitlab-ci.yml file consisting of multiple gitlab jobs and stages. Some jobs run on specific git branches when code is merged to that branch and some jobs are scheduled.

I want to create a scheduled CI/CD pipeline in Gitlab which only contains specific scheduled jobs and not all the scheduled jobs. Is that possible?

For Example this is my gitlab-ci.yml file.

```
stages:
  build
  test
  deploy
  scheduled-test-1
  scheduled-test-2
  scheduled-test-3

build:
  script:
  - echo $Service_Version
  only:
  - develop
  except:
  - schedules

test:
  script:
  - echo $Service_Version
  only:
  - develop
  except:
  - schedules

deploy:
  script:
  - echo $Service_Version
  only:
  - develop
  except:
  - schedules

scheduled-test-1:
  script:
  - echo $Service_Version
  only:
  - schedules

scheduled-test-2:
  script:
  - echo $Service_Version
  only:
  - schedules

scheduled-test-3:
  script:
  - echo $Service_Version
  only:
  - schedules
```

Now, when I create a schedule then all the three schedule tests are seen on the pipeline. I want to create three schedules which has scheduled-test-1, scheduled-test-2 and scheduled-test-3 separately. How is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`only:variables:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyvariables--exceptvariables) (or equivalent `rules:`) and set those variables in your schedules.

For example, if you set the following:

```
job_x:
  only:
    variables:
      - $SCHEDULE_VARIABLE_X
```

Then when you [create a schedule](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html#add-a-pipeline-schedule) you can set the variable `SCHEDULE_VARIABLE_X` in that individual schedule, which will let you control whether `job_x` runs for that schedule.

You can set the `only:variables:` for each job and variables for each schedule accordingly to get the control you want.

Comment: more explanation would be nicer

Comment: @canbax added some more explanation there. Hopefully that is more helpful now.